# Keep generic list values after postback error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting "Type 'ViewStateTest._Default+sInfo' in Assembly... is not marked as serializable" error when trying to keep generic list values after postback, what am I doing wrong here?

code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<sInfo> InfoList1 = new List<sInfo>();
    sInfo Info1;
    struct sInfo
    {
        public int LSR;
        public string BrandAcc;
        public string CreateDate;
        public string QName;
    }

    private void CreateArray()
    {
        Info1.LSR = 2;
        Info1.BrandAcc = "AA";
        Info1.CreateDate = "12/12/2011";
        Info1.QName = "Completed";
        InfoList1.Add(Info1);
    }       

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["arrayListInViewState"] != null)
        {
            InfoList1 = (List<sInfo>)ViewState["arrayListInViewState"];                
        }
        else
        {
            // ArrayList isn't in view state, so we need to load it from scratch.
            CreateArray();
        }
        // Code that uses PageArrayList.
        Label1.Text = InfoList1[0].LSR.ToString();
        Label2.Text = InfoList1[0].BrandAcc;
        Label3.Text = InfoList1[0].CreateDate;
        Label4.Text = InfoList1[0].QName;
    }

    void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save PageArrayList before the page is rendered.
        ViewState.Add("arrayListInViewState", InfoList1);
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

html code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTableTopInfoCount" runat="server" Value="0" />
            <div id="Container">                            
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>                 
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>                    
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
struct sInfo
```

Objects that go into viewstate need to be marked serialializable.